# Using PHP sessions causes page to expire from cache when returning from another site

Tags: php, html, session

I have a form in which the first button posts back to the form; the second button posts to a form at another website; the third button posts to another form at my website.

I am trying to pass a variable from form1.php to form2.php using sessions. The problem is that if I click the second button and then click `Back' to get back to my site, the browser says that the page is not in the cache and I have to reload it. Of course, If I comment out both calls to session_start, I get back to my page as I left it.

What am I doing wrong? See code below.

form1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<html>
  <head></head>

<body>  

<form id="form1" action="form1.php" method="post">
<! -- various controls -->
  <input type="submit" onclick="form1.action='form1.php';" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="form1.action='http://server.anotherdomain/form';" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="form1.action='form2.php'; return true;" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

form2.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $form1Var = $_SESSION["form1Var"];
  /* etc. */
?>  
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<form action="form2.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $form1Var?>" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the `submit` field on `form2.php`?

Comment: This is less about PHP and more about how to invalidate caching from pressing the back button on the browser. You should revise your question.

Comment: @Zsw:You want me to cancel this question, ask another and then you will answer it? OK. I can ask a new question entitled "How do you invalidate caching from pressing the back button the browser", but how do I withdraw this question?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari:the real form2 has a submit button that posts to form2. i was just trying to save some typing,

Comment: @Zsw: By the way, if I do the same thing in ASP.NET, I don't have this problem.

Comment: @TestUser No, I don't know the answer to your question. However, I believe you will get more attention if you actually ask the correct question. You can edit this question or just ask a new one. I am not familiar with ASP.NET so i can't answer you, sorry. But that sounds like useful information to include in the question.

Comment: Try using method="get", or using links instead of form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call `string session_cache_limiter ([ string $cache_limiter ] )` with an appropriate value for $cache_limiter before calling session_start. I am using "private_no_expire", which ensures that the Expire header is never sent to the browser.